# Overloading Primitive Operator (C#)

Tags: c#, double, operator-overloading

Is there a way I can overload primitives, for example addition with doubles? I want to automatically round the doubles whenever an operation is performed. My current code is this:

```
    class Test{
    public static double operator +(double x, double y){
        return Math.Round(x + y)
    }
}
```

but there's an unfortunate error that says "One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type".

Comment: You can't. Thankfully.

Comment: Why is this thankful?

Comment: Because it provides little to no benefit and a huge amount of potential for error.

Comment: Because chaos would ensue

Comment: You can only override operators on types you have control over yourself.

Comment: what would happen if I create another class and overload the same operator? and for example how would I know if + operator for ints is not overloaded any of the referenced assemblies? in that case you can't even be sure 2+2=4

Comment: Why wouldn't I be sure if I implemented the operator? But I see how that would be undesirable. Still, more control is better at least for me and I'd like to control how my numbers behave in my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't overload operators on primitive types. This would cause havoc in your codebase.

What you can do instead, is to create a simple wrapper around the primitive type, let's say `RoundedDouble`:

```
public struct RoundedDouble : IEquatable<RoundedDouble>, IComparable<RoundedDouble>
{
    public readonly double Value;

    public RoundedDouble(double value)
    {
        Value = Math.Round(value); // Or anything else
    }

    public static implicit operator RoundedDouble(double value)
    {
        return new RoundedDouble(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator double(RoundedDouble wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is RoundedDouble)
            return ((RoundedDouble)other).Value == Value;

        return false;
    }

    public string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    // Add your operators here, and implement the interfaces
}
```

This is a structure. It has the same value semantics as a `double`.

Extend it by adding the operators, and by implementing *at least* `IEquatable<RoundedDouble>` and `IComparable<RoundedDouble>`.

Answer (score 5):

No, and this would be *horrible*. Users using your library would suddenly get different behaviors from their `double` variables!

You *can* write and use a wrapper object however:

```
public struct MyDouble
{
     public double Value {get; set;}

     public MyDouble(double initValue)
     {
         Value = initValue;
     }         

     public static double operator +(MyDouble x, MyDouble y){
        return Math.Round(x.Value + y.Value)
     }
}
```

You can also make it castable to/from a double, among other options. This way users *know* they are using your object and won't be surprised when their math operations are rounded.

If you want to assign from a simple double, you would need to define an *implicit* operator, similar to that of `Nullable<T>` ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,83)):

```
 public static implicit operator MyDouble(double value) {
            return new MyDouble(value);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the sake of keeping everything neat and simple, is it possible to have Value automatically be called by calling the class? This way, I way, I can easily do Number = 1 instead of Number.Value = 1.

Comment: @user2994455 Yes, using the `implicit` cast operator.