# C# overload operators for primitive types

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operators

Is it possible to overload operators such as `||`, `&&` and `!` for types like `int` and `float`?

Example:

```cs
float a, b; int c;
//instead of this:
return Convert.ToBoolean(a) || Convert.ToBoolean(b) && !Convert.ToBoolean(c);
//do this:
return a || b && !c;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that's only for user defined types

Comment: The page gives the information about which parameters can be overridden and which can't be regardless of premetives or user defined types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OR you have the `|` symbol. For example:

```
return a | b;
```

Would return `true` if either `a` OR `b` was `true`. Otherwise, it would return `false`.

Also, you have the `&` operator with which you can do this:

```
return a & b;
```

This would return `true` if both `a` AND `b` where `true`. Otherwise, it would return `false`. I recommend you to look into to the documentation here for more operators:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

And of course, as the title of the website says(boolean operators), not it is not possible to do this for integers and floats because they don't have any meaning. I mean why would you want to return `2 or 4 & 5`? It just doesn't have any value. Look here if you find anything:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators

**Edit:** It actually depends on what you are doing, as you pointed out it can be useful for certain problems/algorithms like dealing with matrices, etc. But because you didn't necessarily specify what kind of thing you were doing I understood it as for everyday programming. Anyways, above are the operators for integers. I don't think you can overload operators with floats, though.

Also, @SohaibJundi said (great work), instead of `!` you use this:

```
return ~a;
```

This would return the opposite of the value of `a`. Meaning if `a` was `true` it would return `false` and if it was `false` it would return `true`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why would you say it doesn't have any meaning? In C++ any non-zero value maps to true and zero maps to false implicitly. This is useful if, for example, you have a set of inputs in e.g. a game, and you want to - in this case - check if input A is active or if B is and C is not (inputs might be joystick axes mapped to floats)

Comment: Actually, I should have put that it depends on the situation. In everyday common programming it doesn't matter, but when you have matrixes, etc. it can be useful. Point. @MateuszSowiński Thanks.

Comment: *matrices, I meant.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can use the bit-wise operators to achieve this when using integers.</s>

You would use & instead of &&, | instead of || and ~ instead of !.

It would look like this:

```
    int a, b, c;
    //instead of this:
    //return Convert.ToBoolean(a) || Convert.ToBoolean(b) && !Convert.ToBoolean(c);
    //do this:
    return (a | b & ~c) != 0;
```

But in case of floats, you cannot use these operators.

**Edit:**
After giving it more thought, I believe you can't do this. All non zero values get evaluated to true, except zero evaluates to false. Keeping this in mind, and-ing two non zero values using the bit-wise and (&) might evaluate to zero. E.g.: a = 1, b = 2 -> a & b = 0. Also the bit-wise negation (~) would only evaluate to zero if applied on -1. ~1 would evaluate to non zero, when converted to boolean evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

1. from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction#expressions

   > Operator overloading permits user-defined operator implementations to
   >   be specified for operations **where one or both of the operands are of
   >   a user-defined class or struct type.**
   >   [Overloading Primitive Operator (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444312/overloading-primitive-operator-c)
2. from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#operator-overloadability

   > A user-defined type cannot overload the conditional logical operators
   >   && and ||. However, if a user-defined type overloads the true and
   >   false operators and the & or | operator in a certain way, the && or ||
   >   operation, respectively, can be evaluated for the operands of that
   >   type.

for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#user-defined-conditional-logical-operators